# Flask-Restplus is not generating API documentation

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

Here are the relevant parts of app.py

```
def init_api():
    blueprint = Blueprint("api", __name__, url_prefix="/api/v1")
    api.init_app(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(circuit_namespace)
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)


def init_api_auth():
    app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "super-secret-key"
    app.config["JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES"] = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    jwt.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)


init_api()
init_api_auth()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I can access the API resources at /api/v1/ but when I go to 127.0.0.1:5000/ I cannot see any documentation.
According to the official docs, the API doc is available at / but there is a "NOT FOUND" HTTP response in my case.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doc would also be available at `127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1` because of the defined blueprint. The default path is `<server url>/`. Hope this helps.